# Hibernate search : exact phrase matching

Tags: java, hibernate, lucene, hibernate-search

Using Hibernate Search, I cannot manage to search for an exact sentence.

For instance, having the following sentences in my index :

```
1 - New York weather
2 - New York
```

I want to get only the line 2 matching "New York", so I make the following query :

```
qb.phrase().onField("label").sentence("New York").createQuery()
```

But this query returns both "New York" and "New York weather", i.e. my sentence is used like a prefix when I would like to use it like an equals.

How to do this using hibernate search ?

Comment: With or without the mentioned slop factor (http://stackoverflow.com/a/33220345/115835) both sentences would match, since both contain the phrase "New York". If you want to have exact matches you need to look at KeywordAnalyzer and TermQueries. However, this would not make sense if you really index actual multi sentence text.

Answer (score 1):

Under 5.1.2.4 it mentions a 'slop factor'

https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/search/4.1/reference/en-US/html_single/#search-query-querydsl

Try a slop factor of zero?

qb.phrase().withSlop(0).onField("label").sentence("New York").createQuery()

also try using the Lucene API as mentioned in this question.

[Finding exact match using Lucene search API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/977271/finding-exact-match-using-lucene-search-api)

Your use case is a straight forward one and probably doesn't warrant the Hibernate Search query DSL

Comment: I tried the slop factor of zero but it did not work. The slop factor is for the max distance between words in the sentence, but not for extra words after the sentence.

Comment: I will take a look to the Lucene API instead of the Hibernate search one.